# List of every n-th item in a given list

Tags: scala, scala-collections

This is a simple exercise I am solving in Scala: given a list `l` return a new list, which contains every `n-th` element of `l`. If `n > l.size` return an empty list.

```
def skip(l: List[Int], n: Int) = 
  Range(1, l.size/n + 1).map(i => l.take(i * n).last).toList
```

My solution (see above) seem to work but I am looking for smth. simpler. How would you simplify it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
scala> def skip[A](l:List[A], n:Int) = 
         l.zipWithIndex.collect {case (e,i) if ((i+1) % n) == 0 => e} // (i+1) because zipWithIndex is 0-based
skip: [A](l: List[A], n: Int)List[A]

scala> val l = (1 to 10).toList
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

scala> skip(l,3)
res2: List[Int] = List(3, 6, 9)

scala> skip(l,11)
res3: List[Int] = List()
```

Comment: Thank you but this solution does not look much simpler. What is the advantage of this solution ?

Comment: Well it does look simpler to me (mostly from the fact that `zipWithIndex` makes it explicit you're doing something with the indices), but the main benefit is that you don't call `l.take(i).last` (which is equivalent (and slower than) `l(i)`), as getting an element this way is O(n) with lists.

Comment: Also, just tried your solution, calling `skip(l,3)` (with `l = (1 to 10).toList`) returns `List(1,2,3)`, which doesn't seem to be what you want.

Answer (score 21):

Somewhat simpler:

```
scala> val l = (1 to 10).toList
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

// n == 3

scala> l.drop(2).grouped(3).map(_.head).toList
res0: List[Int] = List(3, 6, 9)

// n > l.length

scala> l.drop(11).grouped(12).map(_.head).toList
res1: List[Int] = List()
```

(the toList just to force the iteratot to be evaluated)

Works with infinite lists:

```
Stream.from(1).drop(2).grouped(3).map(_.head).take(4).toList
res2: List[Int] = List(3, 6, 9, 12)
```

Comment: Seems much simpler. How does the complexity of this compare? Intuitively seems about the same, just nicer to read.

Comment: It's O(N). `Grouped` and `map` go over the list just once each, `_.head` and `drop(2)` are constant time

Comment: I like this but just checking maybe now by 2020 there is something more simple builtin like Python `nums[n-1::n]` or still this is the best way?

Comment: Actually it does map out to be very similar now that I think about it

Answer (score 4):

A bit more readable and the loop size is `O(l.length/n)`:

```
def skip(l: List[Int], n: Int) = {
  require(n > 0)
  for (step <- Range(start = n - 1, end = l.length, step = n))
    yield l(step)
}
```

Comment: Thanks you. I have learned about `step` in `Range` from your answer :) However @Marth is probably right about using `zipWithIndex` instead of `l(step)`.

Comment: Doesn't the use of `zipWithIndex` mean more memory footprint and another loop though? This answer does it in only one loop and doesn't create an intermediary list of tuples. :)

Comment: I am afraid `l(step)` loops over the list and takes `O(n)`. I don't know about the memory consumption of `zipWithIndex`. Maybe you are right about it.

Comment: @Michael you are right that `l(step)` is `O(n)` and if we replace `List` with `Vector` in the code then it will be `O(1)`. http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html

Comment: yes, but the exercise requires a list. Moreover if the exercise requires `Seq` (i.e. either a linked list or array) I would prefer `zipWithIndex` for the same performance reasons. So, `zipWithIndex` looks like really _right_ way to handle indices.

Comment: I don't think there's any need to use indices (explicitly) at all. See my answer for an alternative

Answer (score 1):

Fold left approach `O(n)`

```
def skip(xs: List[Int], n: Int) = {
  xs.foldLeft((List[Int](), n)){ case ((acc, counter), x) =>
      if(counter==1)
        (x+:acc,n)
      else
        (acc, counter-1)
  }
  ._1
  .reverse
}

scala > skip(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 3)
```

Tailrec less readable approach `O(n)`

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def skipTR(xs: List[Int], n: Int) = {
  @tailrec
  def go(ys: List[Int], acc: List[Int], counter: Int): List[Int] = ys match {
    case k::ks=>
      if(counter==1)
        go(ks, k+:acc , n)
      else
        go(ks, acc, counter-1)
    case Nil => acc
  }
  go(xs, List(), n).reverse

}
skipTR(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches based in `filter` on indexes, as follows,

```
implicit class RichList[A](val list: List[A]) extends AnyVal {

  def nthA(n: Int) = n match {
    case 0 => List()
    case _ => (1 to a.size).filter( _ % n == 0).map { i => list(i-1)}
  }

  def nthB(n: Int) = n match {
    case 0 => List()
    case _ => list.zip(Stream.from(1)).filter(_._2 % n == 0).unzip._1
  }
}
```

and so for a given list

```
val a = ('a' to 'z').toList
```

we have that

```
a.nthA(5)
res: List(e, j, o, t, y)

a.nthA(123)
res: List()

a.nthA(0)
res: List()
```

**Update**

Using `List.tabulate` as follows,

```
implicit class RichList[A](val list: List[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def nthC(n: Int) = n match {
    case 0 => List()
    case n => List.tabulate(list.size) {i => 
                if ((i+1) % n == 0) Some(list(i)) 
                else None }.flatten
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could omit toList if you don't mind an iterator:

```
 scala> def skip[A](l:List[A], n:Int) =
      l.grouped(n).filter(_.length==n).map(_.last).toList
 skip: [A](l: List[A], n: Int)List[A]

 scala> skip (l,3)
 res6: List[Int] = List(3, 6, 9)
```

Comment: Both the length check and the _.last will be O(n) (that's the n in every-nth, not the size of l). They're not necessary if you shift the starting point so you're taking the first of each group, not the last (see my answer)

Comment: Yeah, good point if performance is more important than simplicity.